# Could not able to get jsp table row values from one page and display the values in text box of another page

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

I need to get the values from my rows inside the table of a jsp page and display it in textbox of another jsp page i tried to do but i could manage to just call  my another page but could not able to get the values from one page to another

My Jquery

```
                       $('tr').click(function () {
        $('tr').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        selectedRow = $(this);
    });

    $("tr").dblclick(function () {
        var td = $(selectedRow).children('td');
        for (var i = 0; i < td.length; ++i) {
            /* alert(i + ': ' + td[i].innerText); */
        }
        var customer =td[0].innerText
        alert('customer :' +customer);
        window.location = "InternalConversion.jsp?customer="+customer;
    });
```

JSP page

```
               <table style="width: 100%;" class="embeddedFIXED" >
                <thead>
                    <tr >
                        <th align="left">Branch</th>
                        <th align="left">City</th>
                        <th align="left">Country</th>
                        <th align="left">Branch Number</th>
                        <th align="left">Entity Type</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <%
                    BranchSearch b1= null;
                        int rownum = 1;
                        Iterator<BranchSearch> i = l1.iterator();
                            while (i.hasNext()) {
                                b1 = (BranchSearch)i.next();
                                String rowStyle = "TIRowAlt";
                                if (rownum % 2 == 0) {
                                    rowStyle = "TIRow";
                                } else {
                                    rowStyle = "TIRowAlt";
                                }
                    %>


                    <tr class="link1 <%=rowStyle%>" onclick="click()">

                        <td align="left" class="br" ><%=b1.getBranch()%></td>
                        <td align="left"><%=b1.getCity()%></td>
                        <td align="left"><%=b1.getCountry()%></td>
                        <td align="left"><%=b1.getBranchnumber()%></td>
                        <td align="left"><%=b1.getEntitytype()%> </td>

                    </tr>
                    <%
                            rownum++;
                            }
                        %>
                    </tbody>
                      </table>
```

Comment: Just put the table in a template and use ajax to call the controller where it returns the table. Then you can use any value of table like you want,

Comment: can show an example link so that i can able to follow it up

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ here is the documentation as well as the examples

Comment: thank you for the link i found a solution for edited  my java script might be useful for  someone